# java EJB: The import javax.ejb cannot be resolved

Tags: java, ejb

I am reading the book Getting Started with WebSphere Application Server Community Edition.

I created an EJB project with Eclipse EE.

```
import javax.ejb.Local;
```

Error: The import javax.ejb cannot be resolved

I don't know why I cannot import this class.

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer.

I have WAS 7.0 installed - I can add the j2ee jar to my classpath
or
I have Glashfish3 installed which has javaee.jar; I can add that to my classpath as well

Comment: Specifically, WAS_HOME/dev/JavaEE/j2ee.jar is intended for compilation.

Comment: What's the difference in that jar and the one in WAS_HOME/lib/ ?

Comment: WAS_HOME/lib/ is product internals.  IBM might decide to remove or rename the JAR in a future release.  It might work for your local installation, but it's not a good idea for compilation scripts (batch, ant, etc.).  It's a best practice to use WAS_HOME/dev/.

Comment: If you r deploying the bean in GlassFish Server, then you will get those jar files in %GLASSFISH_HOME%/modules/javax.ejb.jar which will solve the problem type resolution.

Comment: If using JBoss7, then add jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec.1.0.1.Final.jar as an External jar in Eclipse.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Probably the comments under the question already answered this, but just in case clarification is needed:

1) In Eclipse, right click on the project --> properties --> java build path

2) Click on add external JAR

3) Add c:\glassfish4\glassfish\lib\javaee.jar
(Your directory path to this JAR can of course be different.)

--> Ok the dialog, and now Eclipse should be able to see javax.ejb.* classes.

Comment: What if you're on Linux?

Answer (score 5):

Please note that this jar file is useful in development, but you need not (should not?) deploy it along with your war or ear files, because the application server container has its own runtime Java EE environment.